# How to find areas in graph using java programming?

Tags: java, graph

[Graph pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roRJf.jpg)

In this graph , there are eight areas namely A,B,C,D,E,F,G and H.

Comment: This can be a very complicated question, depending on many factors. To start with, what format do you have your graph in? Is it a PNG file? Is it a scan of the literal notebook paper you showed? Is it a pair of mathematical functions?

Comment: I am working with javafx graph view. I want to find the area with mouse cursor

Answer (score 1):

Note: x and y need to be float or double, and the y-coordinate probably needs to be inverted, as screen coordinates typically start at the top.

```
if (x < 50.0 && y < 50.0 && x > 0.0 && y > 0.0) {
  if (x / y < 25.0 / 50.0) {
    System.out.println("A")
  } else if (x / y < 50.0 / 25.0) {
    System.out.println("B")
  } else {
    System.out.println("C")
  }
}
```

p.s. the question was edited after this answer was posted. Previously, it was only covering the top right quadrant, so now they seem out of sync.

Comment: It's roughly the same for all 4 quadrants -- just adjust the check on the first line and make sure the other checks are in order of increasing ratios

Comment: I have some doubt in calculating AC,E and G this areas. https://i.stack.imgur.com/roRJf.jpg

Comment: Give an answer.

Comment: The question seems to be closed now. If you have a new question, the right thing to do is to ask a new question, not to edit the original question, making questions and answers go out of sync.

Comment: New question  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66987036/find-areas-in-graph-using-java-programming

Comment: Please give an answer.  I stucked more than a week . Help me .